# Listen to my audiobooks on iphone6 that are not bought from itunes

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, file-transfer, audiobook

Total Apple noob here.

I have a macbook running yosemite 10.10.5 and an iphone six.

I have some audiobooks in mp3 format on the macbook. How can I listen to these audiobooks on the iphone?

-I plug my iphone into the macbook.....it does not show up in finder

-it does show up in itunes. I dragged and dropped the mp3s into my iphones audiobooks folder in itunes. It transfers, and when done, the audiobooks library is still empty. When I use the files app on my phone it says I still have 0 files. The audiobooks then show up in my music library, and can only be accessed from apple music app (which does not play audiobooks well).

-The audiobook files do not show up on my files system on the iphone when I try to access them with third party audio book apps.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. My mp3 audiobooks are not purchased from itunes.

Comment: Whether they're purchased in or outside of iTunes, it's the same issue.  Did you try the solution?